# How to find out the source of iphone CoreLocation Data?

Tags: iphone, core-location

Core Location uses the available GPS, cell, and Wi-Fi networks to determine the user Location.How do I find out the current Source?.Is it possible?.Thanks
Note. suppose if the source is cellular i use some calculations to improve accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you can determine is the accuracy and the age of the reading. The specific location sources can be blended together and they aren't exposed. Review the LocateMe sample app to see how to evaluate these.